# Qualquer um analisa sinalizações?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Qualquer pessoa, desde que possua a reputação mínima exigida para a permissão, pode analisar uma sinalização?

Minha pergunta é especificamente para saber se os usuários podem analisar **inclusive** as sinalizações feitas contra eles mesmos. Ex: Eu sinalizo uma resposta do Usuário X e o próprio Usuário X aprova/rejeita a sinalização.

Pra mim isso é errado porque se A sinaliza B é porque A acredita que B está errado e B 99% das vezes B não vai dar o braço a torcer de que está errado. Então, a partir do momento que B analisa e a aprova a sinalização feita contra uma postagem do próprio B, anula-se o propósito de uma sinalização.

Fiquei realmente chateado com uma sinalização que eu fiz sobre uma resposta de um tópico no qual minha resposta foi tão curta quanto a sinalizada (e tão certa quanto) mas eu tive a decência de apenas comentar.

E o sinalizado aprovou a própria sinalização, invalidando meu direito de opinião e pior! Ainda justificou de forma extremamente grosseira.

Ah! E caso este apareça por aqui, nem adianta pedir desculpas falsas publicamente.

Comment: Como assim? Apenas os moderadores analisam sinalizações.

Comment: Por isso estou justamente perguntando quem tem esse tipo de poder porque pelo que eu sei as ferramentas de moderador, incluindo lidar com sinalizações, requer no mínimo 2.000 pontos. O indivíduo em questão está bem longe disso.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto De qual pergunta estamos falando? Os moderadores podem tomar ações imediatas, mas quanto aos itens das filas de análise, é preciso passar pela aprovação de mais de uma pessoa, então mesmo que o usuário possa votar na própria análise, ele não tem a palavra final. Quanto a ser injusto ele participar, não sei, afinal ele ganhou o direito perguntando e respondendo como qualquer outro usuário.

Comment: O usuário não pode votar em uma análise contra ele, o sistema protege contra isso e o usuário não a enxerga na fila de análises.

Comment: @bfavaretto na vdd depende do tipo de sinalização, não é mesmo? Se eu sinalizar como "Baixa qualidade" ela vai para a fila de análises, assim como vários outros tipos de sinalizações também vão para lá.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Respostas vs. Comentários

Antes de mais nada, me parece que seu único critério para definir se algo é uma resposta ou um comentário é a quantidade de caracteres.

Eu sei que respostas demasiadamente curtas são ruins porque geralmente o usuário não responde adequadamente o que foi perguntado. Mas justamente aqui está o ponto.

Não é porque algo é curto que deve ser necessariamente postado como um comentário. Um comentário é um **comentário**, algo tangente ao assunto, uma observação, uma pergunta para tirar dúvidas, etc.

Por outro lado, uma resposta é qualquer coisa que efetivamente *responda* à questão. Ser prolixo não é sinônimo de qualidade.

Se o tópico a que você se refere é o *Syntactic Sugar no PHP*, então você teve todo o direito de dar a sua opinião em forma de comentário, assim como os usuários que responderam tiveram todo o direito, afinal parece que todos responderam à questão.

É lógico que alguns citaram fontes, outros não, alguns deram explicações maiores, outros menores. Contudo, eu vejo todas elas respondendo à questão.

É claro que muitas vezes é uma questão um tanto subjetiva, mas neste caso em particular a maior diferença que vejo entre seu comentário e as respostas é que você disse coisas como "eu acho" e "queria ter certeza". Isso realmente seria ruim numa resposta.

## Respostas que não são respostas

Ao contrário do que você entendeu, sua flag não foi rejeitado pelo próprio autor. Aliás, não sei de onde você inferiu isso.

Entenda que os moderadores não são ditadores no site. O que costumamos remover são respostas que não são respostas de verdade, como comentários ou pedidos de ajuda.

Respostas erradas ou de pouca qualidade serão negativadas pelos usuários e terão o seu destino traçado pela comunidade.

Particularmente quando vejo um caso desses, costumo instruir o usuário a reformular a resposta ou a removê-la.

## O que fazer com respostas que você ache ruim?

Se você não concorda com uma resposta por estar errada ou achar ruim, opinativa, etc., simplesmente vote contra ela.

Claro, você pode sinalizar para os moderadores se achar adequada. Pode ainda levar a discussão para o meta, como fez agora.

## Vai com calma

Depois de tudo isso, agora peço que tenha calma. Você tirou várias conclusões precipitadas e seus comentários chegaram a ser ofensivos.

Primeiro, você não foi "vítima" de uma "panelinha" ou coisa parecido. As razões eu já expliquei nos tópicos anteriores.

Segundo, a justificativa dada não tem nada de grosseiro, foi apenas direta com um conselho sobre como agir, o que também expliquei acima. Cuidado ao interpretar conselhos com a cabeça quente.

Enfim, evite levar as coisas para o lado pessoal. O autor da resposta que você sinalizou não tem nada a ver com o ocorrido.

Além disso, mesmo que você ainda discorde que da resposta, ela tem vários votos positivos e foi aceita pelo OP, o que dá credibilidade o suficiente a ela.

Lógico que a minha resposta não é a palavra definitiva em nada, afinal aqui é um espaço democrático. E o processo democrático mostrou, pelo menos, que as respostas são boas o suficiente para a pergunta.

Comment: Entendi seu ponto de vista e agradeço pela resposta. Talvez, estressado, eu tenha me excedido um pouco e descontado na(s) pessoa(s) errada(s). Sou homem para assumir meu erro e peço desculpas tanto pelo comentário ofensivo feito contra a Comunidade (hoje removido) quanto por direta ou indiretamente ter acusado a(s) pessoa(s) errada(s).

Comment: No entanto, reitero o fato da falto de tato de quem rejeitou a sinalização. Se é uma resposta automatizada, ela precisa ser revista pois soou bastante rude. E ainda fica a sugestão de mostrar no relatório de sinalizações não apenas o nome de usuário do snalizado, mas também de quem o rejeitou.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Fico muito feliz de ver sua atitude. Você é um exemplo de maturidade e sinceridade! Embora não tenha sido eu o autor do comentário, peço desculpas pelo mal entendido em nome da moderação. A única coisa que posso dizer por enquanto é que a intenção não foi ser rude de forma alguma, mas com certeza vou repassar sua colocação e fazemos o possível para não passarmos a mensagem errada.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Quanto à sua sugestão, é improvável que o sistema venha a mostrar o usuário que fez uma sinalização ou que a rejeitou, pois a privacidade é um fator importante para não inibir os usuários de sinalizar ou atuar, tanto que em algumas situações até os moderadores não tem acesso ao autor. Este é um mecanismo para evitar favorecimento.